# How do I alphabetically sort an array of strings without any sort functions? Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, numpy

When solving the following problem:
"Assuming you have a random list of strings (for example: a, b, c, d, e, f, g), write a program that will sort the strings in alphabetical order. 
You may not use the sort command."

I run into the problem of running strings through the following code, which sometimes gets me duplicated strings in final list

I am fairly new to python and our class just started to look at numpy, and functions in that module, and im not sure of any being used in the code (except any sort function).

```
import numpy as np

list=[]
list=str(input("Enter list of string(s): "))
list=list.split()
print() # for format space purposes
listPop=list
min=listPop[0]
newFinalList=[]

if(len(list2)!=1):
    while(len(listPop)>=1):
        for i in range(len(listPop)):
            #setting min=first element of list
            min=listPop[0]
            if(listPop[i]<=min):
                min=listPop[i]
                print(min)    
        listPop.pop(i)
        newFinalList.append(min)
    print(newFinalList)
else:
    print("Only one string inputted, so already alphabatized:",list2)
```

Expected result of ["a","y","z"]

["a","y","z"]

Actual result...

Enter list of string(s): a y z

a
a
a
['a', 'a', 'a']

Enter list of string(s): d e c

d
c
d
d
['c', 'd', 'd']

Comment: This is definitely not going to be easy for a beginner, but here's something you can do. Make a Numpy array of letters `letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'...]`. Then, when you get a string, use `np.where()` or `np.argwhere()` to get the index of the letter ('a' will be 0, 'z' will be 25). Then, after getting the indices of two letters, you can determine which is smaller.

If you don't need to use Numpy, you can use a string instead: `letters = 'abcdef...'`. Then, use `letters.find('a')` to get the index of the letter ('b' would be the second position). Once again, compare the indices.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is allowed but convert it to [ascii code](http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html) and work with numbers

Comment: Do they expect you to use `numpy` in this sorting?  or is this sorting task left over from some unit that you studied before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection sort: for each index `i` of the list, select the smallest item at or after `i` and swap it into the `i`th position.  Here's an implementation in three lines:

```
# For each index i...
for i in range(len(list)):
    # Find the position of the smallest item after (or including) i.
    j = list[i:].index(min(list[i:])) + i
    # Swap it into the i-th place (this is a no-op if i == j).
    list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
```

- `list[i:]` is a slice (subset) of `list` starting at the `i`th element.
- `min(list)` gives you the smallest element in `list`.
- `list.index(element)` gives you the (first) index of `element` in `list`.
- `a, b = b, a` atomically swaps the values of `a` and `b`.

The trickiest part of this implementation is that when you're using `index` to find the index of the smallest element, you need to find the index within the same `list[i:]` slice that you found the element in, otherwise you might select a duplicate element in an earlier part of the list.  Since you're finding the index relative to `list[i:]`, you then need to add `i` back to it to get the index within the entire `list`.

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation of how you're implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Quick sort for same:

```
def partition(arr,low,high): 
    i = ( low-1 )        
    pivot = arr[high]
    for j in range(low , high):     
        if arr[j] <= pivot:         
            i = i+1
            arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
    arr[i+1],arr[high] = arr[high],arr[i+1] 
    return ( i+1 ) 

def quickSort(arr,low,high): 
    if low < high:      
        pi = partition(arr,low,high)        
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1) 
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high) 

arr = ['a', 'x', 'p', 'o', 'm', 'w'] 
n = len(arr) 
quickSort(arr,0,n-1) 
print ("Sorted list is:") 
for i in range(n): 
    print ("%s" %arr[i]),
```

output:

```
Sorted array is:
a m o p w x
```

Answer (score 0):

Mergesort:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import islice

def _ms(a, n):
    return islice(a,n) if n<2 else merge(_ms(a,n//2),_ms(a,n-n//2))

def mergesort(a):
    return type(a)(_ms(iter(a),len(a)))

# example

import string
import random

L = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
random.shuffle(L)
print(L)
print(mergesort(L))
```

Sample run:

```
['h', 'g', 's', 'l', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'r', 'j', 'q', 'p', 'm', 'd', 'k', 'w', 'u', 'v', 'y', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```